# How To Compare An Element of Array With Element of another array in a ArrayList?

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist

I have an array and i want to compare the first element of this array with every element of another array in an Arraylist?

The purpose of doing this is to check whether or not the first element of the array exist in the another array of an Arraylist.

is this possible?

if yes, how?

```
         List<List<String>> arrayst = new ArrayList<List<String>>();
         List<List<String>> arrayqu = new ArrayList<List<String>>();
         List<List<String>> arrayya = new ArrayList<List<String>>();

         List<String> items = Arrays.asList(line.split(":",-1));
         // i want to compare 1st element of items with 3 of the list above.
```

Comment: yes possible, pls try and post some code

Comment: What you have done so far?Please add code snippets.

Comment: What's the datatype which the Array holds?

Comment: Yes very much possible. But at first you need to show what have you tried and where are you stuck. We will definately help you only if you have tried at least something from your end.

Comment: @AritroSen my code is too messy, so i just extract the part i want to ask. the code is updated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a different class and try something like this -

```
public class StackOverflow {
public void compare(List<String> items, List<List<String>> list){
    String itemToBeCompared=items.get(0);
    for(List<String> l:list){
        if(l.contains(itemToBeCompared)){
            System.out.println("Its Present");
        }
        else{
            System.out.println("Not Present");
        }
    }
}
}
```

Then in the main method do something like this -

```
List<List<String>> arrayst = new ArrayList<List<String>>();
     List<List<String>> arrayqu = new ArrayList<List<String>>();
     List<List<String>> arrayya = new ArrayList<List<String>>();

     List<String> items = Arrays.asList(line.split(":",-1));
StackOverflow st=new StackOverflow();
st.compare(items,arrayst);
st.compare(items,arrayqu);
st.compare(items,arrayya);
```

Hope this helps! Please let me know if this works for you.